# UILabel with a hyperlink inside a UITableViewCell should open safari webbrowser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with two labels (`UILabel`). The table cells are used to display information / text. Inside some of these cells (not all) there is text in this way set:

```
cell.myTextlabel.text = @"http://www.google.de"
```

Now I want if I click this text / link, a safari webbrowser should open this webpage. How can I do this?

Best Regards Tim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set userInteractionEnabled to YES of your label and add a gesture recognizer to it:

```
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openUrl:)];
gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
[gestureRec release];
```

Then implement the action method:

```
- (void)openUrl:(id)sender
{
    UIGestureRecognizer *rec = (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    id hitLabel = [self.view hitTest:[rec locationInView:self.view] withEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];

    if ([hitLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:((UILabel *)hitLabel).text]];
    }
}
```

Comment: It does the trick, but to make UILabel look like a link one has to subclass from UILabel to redefine the outlook (or to use 3rd party framework) and that's pretty annoying.

Comment: On iOS 6.0 and later you can set the attributedText of the UILabel to have a blue color and an underline.

Comment: why it giving me implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'UIEvent *' is disallowed with ARC when i tried to convert my project in ARC... it was working before. i have use your code id hitLabel = [self.view hitTest:[rec locationInView:self.view] withEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];

Answer (score 4):

If you use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` it will automatically handle link detection.  Set the view's `dataDetectorTypes` to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click event you can open safari browser by the following code
 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];