# Safari web browse not open with URL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am new at iPhone Development.
I have Table view with 6 section each section has one row, in 4Th Section i add UILabel.
This UILabel text is URL (www.google.com).
I want to open safari when i click on This label but i am not success for open safari

i follo this [UILabel with a hyperlink inside a UITableViewCell should open safari webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928868/uilabel-with-a-hyperlink-inside-a-uitableviewcell-should-open-safari-webbrowser)

But it not work.

**My code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor = [Prep defaultBGColor];

        if(indexPath.section == 3)
        {
            self.lblWebsite = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 270, 35)];
            self.lblWebsite.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.lblWebsite.text= @"www.gmail.com";
            self.lblWebsite.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16];
            self.lblWebsite.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            self.lblWebsite.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.lblWebsite.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.lblWebsite];

            UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openUrl:)];
            gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
            gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [self.lblWebsite addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
            [gestureRec release];
       }
    }
  return Cell;
}
```

**Method**

```
- (void)openUrl:(id)sender
{

    UIGestureRecognizer *rec = (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    id hitLabel = [self.view hitTest:[rec locationInView:self.view] withEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];

    if ([hitLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
         NSLog(@"%@",((UILabel *)hitLabel).text);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
    }
}
```

Here what is my mistake ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

u r missing "`http://`"

Answer (score 2):

You done right but as i think use `http://` before `www.google.com` like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])

NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

and i think it may work for you

Answer (score 0):

Just Add "http://" it will work 
Example:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]];
```

Comment: what's new in your answer this solution are given before a long time.