# how to set a clickable URL in UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel, rubymotion

I am trying to set a URL into UILabel such that the label is clickable by the user and opens in the phone's browser.

What is the way to do this?

I tried something like this but it errors out with `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
@url = q.append(UILabel, :url_label).get
@url.text = NSURL.URLWithString('http://www.rubymotion.com')
```

I preferably want to have a text that is clickable rather than showing a long url to the user.

Example: [More Info](http://google.com) rather than http://google.com

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839464/uilabel-string-as-text-and-links

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928868/uilabel-with-a-hyperlink-inside-a-uitableviewcell-should-open-safari-webbrowser

Comment: You need to use UITextView instead of UILabel. [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681965/how-to-make-url-phone-clickable-uilabel)

Comment: use UITextview instead of UILabel it have options to detect links